# python multiply char with an int why the result is 44?

Tags: python, math

```
word = '4'
result = word * 2

print(result)
```

char '4' is equal to value 52 (ASCII)
but why result is 44?

Comment: It's confusing because your string looks numeric. Try "hi"*2 for "hihi"

Comment: because `*` is the *repetition operator* for sequence types, which is what `str` objects are.  The fact that the `str` contains only numerical characters is neither here nor there. This isn't javascript, Python is strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually an integer, it's just concatenating twice the same '4'+'4' char into '44'.
I'd suggest to check out: https://www.pythoncentral.io/use-python-multiply-strings/